# Django 2 models 1 from

Tags: python, django, forms, model

I am creating a project and I will have multiple pdfs per timeline, so I have created these following models:

As a beginner to Django, I am confused as to how to upload the pdf file (that will be uploaded by the user). When I display it on forms, it shows me a field that resembles the one displayed for CHOICES. If I try for one file, it works perfectly but for 2 it doesn't.

Question is: How can I display the FileField from the pdf model?

```
class Pdf(models.Model):
    pdf = models.FileField(upload_to='timelinepdfs')


class Timeline(models.Model):
    header = models.CharField(max_length=30, choices=HEADER_CHOICES)
    age = models.CharField(max_length=6, choices=AGE_CHOICES)
    pdfs = models.ForeignKey(Pdf, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

This is my forms.py file:

```
class TimelineForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Timeline
        fields = ('header', 'age')

class PdfForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Pdf
        fields = ('pdf',)
```

This is my view.py class:

```
def upload_timeline(request):
    form = TimelineForm()
    return render(request, 'upload_timeline.html', {
        'form': form
    })
```

Comment: Given that you can have multiple `Pdf`s per `Timeline`, shouldn't you define a `ForeignKey` from `Pdf` to `Timeline`?

Comment: Rookie mistake! Just corrected it thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that you can have multiple `Pdf`s per `Timeline`, you should define a `ForeignKey` from `Pdf` to `Timeline`, so:

```
class Timeline(models.Model):
    header = models.CharField(max_length=30, choices=HEADER_CHOICES)
    age = models.CharField(max_length=6, choices=AGE_CHOICES)

class Pdf(models.Model):
    pdf = models.FileField(upload_to='timelinepdfs')
    timeline = models.ForeignKey(Timeline, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

You simply combine the two forms:

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect

def upload_timeline(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = TimelineForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        form_pdf = PdfForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid() and form_pdf.is_valid():
            timeline = form.save()
            form_pdf.instance.timeline = timeline
            form_pdf.save()
            return redirect('some-view')
    else:
        form = TimelineForm()
        form_pdf = PdfForm()
    return render(request, 'upload_timeline.html', {
        'form': form,
        'form_pdf': form_pdf
    })
```

You should replace *`'some-view'`* with the name of a view you redirect to in case the submission is successful to implement the [*Post/Redirect/Get* pattern [wiki]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get).

In your template you then render both forms in the same `<form>` tag:

```
<form method="POST" action={% url 'url-of-upload_timeline' %}">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form }}
    {{ pdf_form }}
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

where *`'url-of-upload_timeline'`* should be replaced with the name of the view of the `upload_timeline` function.

Comment: Thank you!!!!!!!!!!!!! I have been stuck on this for hours! Thank you so much for the help!!